# How can you create and copy unsigned apps to other phones?

Tags: android, sharing

Is there a way to copy an app written by myself from my phone to another device for testing purposes? Something like putting in an SD card with the app on and installing from there? I understand anti-piracy measures would prevent that, but maybe there's a debug option I don't know about? (I hope!)

Edit: In case anyone else has the same question, I'll add what I've found out. You can export an unsigned .apk file from Eclipse by right-clicking the project > Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package. That produces an .apk. This can be copied to an SD card and then, as described below, can be installed from the file. In theory. Installing off SD has failed for me trying my app.

Edit 2: **Final answer**. Unsigned apps will not install, so that Export Unsigned Application Package function isn't much use. You need to follow the SDK instructions for signing an app, which in Eclipse just means r-click package and Export as Android app and fill in some details to create a keystore file. The signed .apk can be installed from within the phone/tablet using the file manager.

Comment: I don;t really think this is astack overflow question but you can simply copy the APK files across and use an android file manager to install. (requires that you have ticked install from untrusted sources in the settings)

Comment: Thanks to those who replied. I don't understand why this is off topic. Software development requires testing apps which means a way of distributing them. My Google-fu was inadequate to find the answer, and I didn't know an .apk could be installed off SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just simply send the .apk file to any device and test it.
but if you have installed the application of your own phone and does not have access to the .apk, you can send it using this application via Bluetooth to other phones.

[Share Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theronrogers.shareapps&hl=en)

and remember that you also have to allow installing unsafe applications by enabling the following option:

> Settings > Applications > Unknown Sources

so you can install the .apk file on any other device than yours.